# Client Side Configuration in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Silverlight app. I need to add some config settings on just my Silverlight app. I thought there was a app.config file I could add. Is that true? If so, how do I get config values from the app.config file in my Silverlight app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is supported to read application settings from an app.config file directly in Silverlight. What you could do is create another XML file and read those settings manually ([example](http://www.mohamedibrahim.net/blog/2010/01/27/creating-and-using-silverlight-app-settings-webconfig-configuration-applicatioin-settings-to-change-wcf-service-address-after-deployment-servicereferencesclientconfig-servicereferences-clientconfig/) code).

If you do not run this as a standalone desktop application (out-of-browser) you could also make use of the initialization parameters (initParams [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838255(v=vs.95).aspx)) that you can pass to a Silverlight application using an ASPX page. To keep it dynamic, you could use querystring parameters.

The ASPX code to run a silverlight application with InitParams:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="silverlightControlHost">
            <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" id="Xaml1" width="100%" height="100%">
              <param name="initParams" value="k1=<%=Request.QueryString["key1"] %>,k2=<%=Request.QueryString["key2"] %>"/>
            </object>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Then in your startup module (app.xaml.cs) do something like:

```
public App()
        {
            Startup += ApplicationStartup;
}
private void ApplicationStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
                if (e.InitParams.ContainsKey("k1"))
                {
                    var key1Value = e.InitParams["k1"];
                }
            }
        }
```